# Browsers based on Chromium has "Multi-Account Containers"?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, chromium, bing

As a Firefox user, my life depends on the extension "Multi-Accounts Containers", this extension basely allow-me to use different containers tabs as much I want. Just a change between tabs and I go to a completely new "environment" browser.

Like every one when I see that Microsoft will launch a type of ChatGPT with Bing, I try to use the Edge Browser based in Chromium to try the new feature in the "original browser". The first thing I do was see the profiles feature in Edge and this is why I making this...

WHY EDGE AND CHROME NOT ALLOW ME USE PROFILES AS TABS!? JUST WHY??!
are you saying that every user of chrome and edge when want change between profiles HAS TO OPEN A NEW WINDOW? (I'm so sorry for you guys)

So I want to ask if has a method to open profiles in Edge as tabs and I'm just dumb, 'cause they don't have [Contextual identities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextualIdentities), right?
And if not have a method to use as tabs, has a method to ask them to create this feature by pressure of the community?

https://community.brave.com/t/equivalent-of-multi-account-containers-or-temporary-containers-extension-ff/135573

https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/34

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no equivalent of Multi-Account Containers in Edge. If you want to provide feedback about this, you can press **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge. Edge team will check the feedback and improve the product continuously. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Oh thanks. I'll do this and hope for them put something similar soon